# How to exclude tags from scraping that have a specific tag as a child

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get all the paragraphs of an article using BeautifulSoup and exclude the paragraph tags that instead of the paragraph have another tag, such as an  tag in them or if they do have an  tag as a child only get the text of the paragraph.

This is a part of the HTML

```
<div class="entry-content clearfix">
  <div class="entry-thumbnail>
  <p> In as name to here them deny wise this. As rapid woody my he me which. </p>
  <p> <a href="https://blabla"/> </p> 
  <p> Performed suspicion in certainty so frankness by attention pretended.
      Newspaper or in tolerably education enjoyment. </p>
  <p> <a href="https://blabla"/> When be draw drew ye. Defective in do recommend
      suffering. House it seven in spoil tiled court. Sister others marked 
      fat missed did out use.</p>
</div>
```

and this is what I have done till now

```
 contents = []
 content = soup.find('div', { "class": "entry-content clearfix"}).find_all("p")
    for p in content:
        if not (p.find(findChildren("a"))):
            contents[p] = content
    if (content):
        dic['content'] = content
    else: 
        print("ARTICLE:", i, "HAS NO content")
        dic['body'] = "No content"
```

Comment: Please help us understand your expected result. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the `findChildren()` function yet? You could just check for empty `list`.

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ I am expecting to obtain all the paragraphs of an article (the content of the article) and add it to a dictionary. However, I don't want to include all the "junk" such as unnecessary <a> tags that are part of some paragraphs.

Comment: @AeroBlue I've already tried that but it wasn't working

Comment: show the expected text to be returned

Comment: @QHarr That's the output I aim to get. If I could also remove the tags, it would be even better. <p> In as name to here them deny wise this. As rapid woody my he me which. </p><p> Performed suspicion in certainty so frankness by attention pretended.
      Newspaper or in tolerably education enjoyment. </p><p> When be draw drew ye. Defective in do recommend
      suffering. House it seven in spoil tiled court. Sister others marked 
      fat missed did out use.</p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function get_text(). It will extract the text from paragraphs. Reference: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/beautifulsoup/beautifulsoup-4-python

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
contents = """<div class="entry-content clearfix">
  <div class="entry-thumbnail>
  <p> In as name to here them deny wise this. As rapid woody my he me which. </p>
  <p> <a href="https://blabla"/> </p> 
  <p> Performed suspicion in certainty so frankness by attention pretended.
      Newspaper or in tolerably education enjoyment. </p>
  <p> <a href="https://blabla"/> When be draw drew ye. Defective in do recommend
      suffering. House it seven in spoil tiled court. Sister others marked 
      fat missed did out use.</p>
</div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, "lxml")
print(soup.get_text())
```

Result:

```
Performed suspicion in certainty so frankness by attention pretended.
      Newspaper or in tolerably education enjoyment. 
  When be draw drew ye. Defective in do recommend
      suffering. House it seven in spoil tiled court. Sister others marked 
      fat missed did out use.
```